# Wrong path when try to restore MBR with dd ! Any way to fix? [solved]

Tags: hard-drive, dd, mbr

My laptop hawe 1TB hdd, with few of partition. Ubuntu is 125gb and hawe few others.

I backup my MBR with command:

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=mbr.bkp bs=512 count=1
```

Today, after some issues i try to restore it and i miss-type command. i didn't type 1 on sda.

**> I think that i done wrong**

```
dd if=mbr.bkp of of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1
```

And when i reboot i lost option to start linux. 
At this point my live usb GPart show me this
[image]

is it all lost or there is way to fix this ? At last is there way to create something to restore data and files ?

Comment: There is little reason to backup MBR with dd, but you may want to back up partition table info part of MBR with this for sda: `sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda >parts_sda.txt and copy to another drive.  If you ever need to fix a BIOS boot version of grub to MBR, easier to just reinstall grub from any live installer. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System or: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader

Answer (score 1):

Luckily you have only overwritten the first 512 bytes of the disk, that is where the MBR normally resides (`/dev/sda1` is the begin of the first partition, it does not contain the MBR).

I have successfully used Testdisk in the past when the partition table was wiped. See these links for more details:

- [Recovering Partition Tables - GParted manual](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dhelp-manual#gparted-recover-partition-table)
- [I've wiped my partition table using gparted, is there a way to recover my partition?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/93681/8250)
- http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

The command that is suggested in the manual is `testdisk /dev/sda`. Be sure to read above references to learn more about the steps.

Comment: reinstalling grub may be necessary if it is a legacy boot

Comment: At this point i download:
https://gparted.sourceforge.io/livecd.php

and lčive usb it and is running now. If im correct in gparted GUI there is  Device > Attempt Data Rescue 
Yust to be sure is that it ?

Comment: @dMatija yes you can try that. And ravery is right, testdisk would only recovery the partition table (the most important part imo). After that you still need to reinstall grub to make booting your system possible.

Comment: I restore table's as they are in original setup =)
But when i try to "dd ..." my original mbr it dosn't applay it to work and live testdisk lost option to create it as i was able on first analyze.

When i leave hdd boot shows me only: "1234F: _ "
=\ gues i hawe restore MBR on other way...

Comment: @dMatija Congratulations, now it is time for a backup ;-) And as I said, `/dev/sda1` does not contain your original MBR, try following instructions to restore your bootloader (likely GRUB if you use Ubuntu).

Comment: @Lekensteyn i backup my mbr when i setup all of my ubuntu.
I was i in rush and i mistype it =( 
I backup all of my data no problem. Just newer done this stupid thing so i panic more then my kernel =)